# Migrate user data (Core Data) from Objective-C app to Xamarin rewrite

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xamarin

I currently have a native iOS app written in Objective-C that stores some data using Core Data. If I were to rewrite the entire app using Xamarin, is there anyway to keep the data users already have on their device after the app is rewritten and updated?

Comment: if you use the same bundle id for the new app, the existing data should remain on the device and be accessible to the new app.

Comment: If the database is in a special user group folder, you will need to use the exact same folder as well (For example, iOS and WatchOS can store data in the same database via a shared group).

Comment: @sbonkosky Have you found an answer for this? I'm in the same situation.